# Command Line Python Comma Separated User Input int Values

Tags: python, math

math.pow (base/exponent) requires comma separated values...working fine for pre-assigned values, but having trouble with user-submitted values (experimenting in command line). Help appreciated as I want to develop this kind of thing eventually making a basic math test.

```
exp = int(raw_input()) 

    while exp:
        print math.pow(int(raw_input))
```

The errors I'm getting are

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3' (which seems weird as this is an exponent, not log function...)

When I try:

```
exp = (raw_input()) 

while exp:
    print math.pow(exp)
```

I get error:

> pow expected 2 arguments, got 1

Even though I'm submitting 2,3 for example (with comma).

I also tried concatenating the input with .split, but got error regarding pow requiring integers, not "list."

Comment: raw_input returns a string, convert it to int using, well `int()` (you need to `split()` it first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter an input with a comma, you get a tuple. You can either use

```
eval(raw_input())
```

Or just

```
input()
```

To get this from a string to a usable format. Once you have a tuple, you can use * notation to "unpack" the tuple. So instead of calling math.pow((2, 3)), where the one argument is the tuple (2, 3), you will be calling math.pow(2, 3).

```
>>> exp = input()
2, 3
>>> math.pow(*exp)
8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`"2,3"` is a string, passing this to a function won't make it act like two different parameters separated by `,`(as you expected).

```
>>> def func(arg):
...     print arg
...     
>>> func('a, b') 
a, b              # arg is a variable that stores the passed string
```

You should convert that string into two numbers first  by splitting it at comma first and then applying int() to each if it's item.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(*map(int, '2,3'.split(',')))
8.0
```

First split the string at ',' using `str.split`:

```
>>> '2,3'.split(',')
['2', '3']               #str.split returns a list
```

Now as we need integers so apply `int()` to each value:

```
>>> map(int, '2,3'.split(',')) #apply int() to each item of the list ['2', '3']
[2, 3]
```

Now as `pow` expects two arguments so you can use `*` notation to unpack this list and pass
the items to `math.pow`.

```
>>> math.pow(*[2 , 3])
8.0
```

A even simpler way would be to use sequence unpacking:

```
>>> a, b = [2, 3]
>>> math.pow(a, b)
8.0
```

There's another tool in python library that can convert comma separated items in a string into a tuple:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('1, 2')
(1, 2)
>>> a,b  = literal_eval('1, 2')
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit much for the OP to follow considering the question?

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, I will re-visit the split function.